# How to download documents by doc id

Tags: google-apps-script

```
function getDocuments(user){
  var scope = 'https://docs.google.com/feeds/';
  //oAuth
  user="user@yourdomain.com"
  var fetchArgs = googleOAuth_('docs', scope);
  var url = scope + user+'/private/full?v=3&alt=json';
  var urlFetch = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, fetchArgs);
  var json=Utilities.jsonParse(urlFetch.getContentText())
  var entry = json.feed.entry;
  var docs = [];
  for(var i in entry){
    var tempDoc = {};
    for(var j in entry[i]){
      tempDoc.id = entry[i].id.$t.split('%3A')[1];
    }
    docs.push(tempDoc);
  }

  var url='https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/Export?docID='+docs[0]+'&exportFormat=docs'
UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,fetchArgs)

}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Google oAuth
//Used by getDocuments(user)
function googleOAuth_(name,scope) {
  var oAuthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService(name);
  oAuthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken?scope="+scope);
  oAuthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken");
  oAuthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken");
  oAuthConfig.setConsumerKey(consumerKey);
  oAuthConfig.setConsumerSecret(consumerSecret);
  return {oAuthServiceName:name, oAuthUseToken:"always",method:"GET"};
}
```

I am trying above code for downloading the documents by document ID. I have an array of document ID as docs & i am using export format as docs....So please give some suggestion on this code..... 
When i run this code it gives error :
error 302..Moved temporarily..

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 for(var i in entry){
    var tempDoc = {};
    for(var j in entry[i]){
      tempDoc.id = entry[i].id.$t.split('%3A')[1];
    }
//now your splitting your string nicely but you also want to use that
    docs.push(tempDoc.id);
  }

  var url='https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/Export?docID='+docs[0]+'&exportFormat=docs'

//you dont want to use the fetch arguments anymore you have authenticated already
UrlFetchApp.fetch(url)
```

Well good luck with that,

Thomas van Latum

Comment: There is no error in the code bt where is document the downloaded.....How can i get the downloaded document ?

Comment: well you can put it in a variable like this:
var downloadedDoc = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);

But it depends on what you exactly want to do.

Comment: I have to store document at different location....for this, i need all contents of that document..here, i am facing problem....I am getting, id and title of the document but bot content

Comment: i have to store it at 2 locations : 
one is at google cloud storage & second is at another account's google docs/drive......

Comment: I have to do it by google apps script....I have tried many urls for this but didn't get feasible solution.....here examples are not in google apps script